# Javascript Validation on form

Tags: javascript, codepen

Just starting with HTML and JavaScript, been set an assignment to use JavaScript for some logical function.  I have created a form and wanted to check that the elements are filled in correctly.  I have tried to look at the duration and ideally wanted to set a minimum value upon submission, however it is not working as expected.

I have to use codepen for the assignment which has a separate column for JavaScript but I have put the code used in the form, not sure what I need to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Student recovery recording</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="newstyle.css" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header><h1>Student Recovery Recording</h1></header>
    <main>
      <div class="container1">
        <p>form content goes here</p>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <form name="myForm" form action="" method="get">
          <div class="form-row">
            <label for="name"> Instructor Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <label for="Exam"> Exam Code:</label>
            <select name="Exam" id="Exam">
              <option value="">--Please choose the correct Exam code--</option>
              <option value="code1">AT017</option>
              <option value="code2">CT154</option>
              <option value="code3">AT317</option>
              <option value="code4">BT141</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <label for="reason"> Reason For Training:</label>
            <select name="reason" id="reason">
              <option value="">
                --Please select the correct reason for training
              </option>
              <option value="train1">ATT</option>
              <option value="train2">ITT</option>
              <option value="train3">ETT</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <label for="date">Date:</label>
            <input type="date" id="date" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <label for="Studentname"> Student Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="Studentname" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <label for="Duration">Duration:</label>
            <input type="time" id="Duration" min="1:00" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
            <textarea name="comment" rows="4" cols="50">
Enter details of work carried out and KLP's covered here...</textarea
            >
          </div>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="myFunction()" />
          <script>
            function myFunction() {
              var text;
              if (document.getElementById("Duration").validity.rangeUnderflow) {
                text = "Not enough Recovery Time";
              } else {
                text = "Recovery Time acceptable";
              }
              document.getElementById("myForm").innerHTML = text;
            }
          </script>
        </form>
      </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <p>
        <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer">
          <img
            style="border: 0; width: 88px; height: 31px"
            src="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/images/vcss"
            alt="Valid CSS!"
          />
        </a>
      </p>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: separate the code into html and javascript with the StackOverflow snippet, `<>`, it will be easier to edit and post  answer with it.

Comment: separate the code into html and javascript with the StackOverflow snippet, `<>`, it will be easier to edit and post  answer with it.

Comment: This appears to be about using codepen, not an actual programming question. Read the help files? https://blog.codepen.io/documentation/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use setTimeOut() method to the set duration trigger the method when the user load the window or the user starting to press the key.

example:

```
      <div class="form-row">
        <label for="name"> Instructor Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" onkeypress="setTimeout(showSubmitButton(), 5000)" /> //trigger showSubmitButton() when key pressed wait 5 sec then run showSubmitButton()
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" style="display:none">// set display to none for hiding the button
      </div>
      <script>
      function showSubmitButton() {
        document.getElementById("submit").style.display = "block" // show the button after 5 sec
      }
      </script>
```

hope this help you